# Mails not received when using Cloudflare DNS and Cpanel server

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, cloudflare, cpanel

I have the following Cloudflare DNS config:

[image]

The mail and ftp are hosted on the Cpanel server. The website is hosted on a separate server, on a VPS. You can see in this image that the mail A record is not proxied through Cloudflare.

The problem is that I can only send emails, I can't receive any email.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? The MX records are pointed to mydomain.com . Should they be pointed to mail.mydomain.com or to the IP address of the Cpanel server?

Is it ok to use Cpanel only for the email? It seems that the problem appears once the domain is pointed to a different IP.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what am I doing wrong? The MX records are pointed to mydomain.com . Should they be pointed to mail.mydomain.com or to the IP address of the Cpanel server?

[MX Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) should point to the server that is configured to accept mail for that domain.

In your case, that's probably your mailservers name.